Help understanding the implications of Security Breach section of an NDA
The paragraph reads:
In the event of a Security Breach, Subcontractor will, without limiting any remedies available to COMPANY hereunder or at law or equity: (i) reimburse COMPANY for the costs incurred by COMPANY to notify any affected individuals and any appropriate legal and regulatory authorities; and (i) pay for the cost of providing credit monitoring services to each such affected individuals for two (2) years from a nationally recognized supplier of such services.
This is part of an NDA/Non-Compete for a job offer.  I am a software engineer. I am concerned that if some breach did occur that I could be on the hook for millions of dollars and potentially ruin my entire life.
This document came from the middle-man.  I'm working for "CLIENT", w/ "SUBCONTRACTOR 1" (who owns this document), and I am a W2 for "SUBCONTRACTOR 2".
I want to know if I am opening myself up to writing a blank check for "SUBCONTRACTOR 1"?  If so, then I want to decline this job which leaves me jobless, but not at risk of losing everything I own.

From the question it is not clear what is the relationship between SUBCONTRACTOR_1 and SUBCONTRACTOR_2 and who are the parties signing this NDA. --- Also: Does the text before the paragraph carefully specify the Security Breach or does it try to make you liable for any security breach?

One downside of contractor work: liability. Usual mitigation: insurance.

I'd take that to an insurer, specifically, and ask if they'd cover it.  Many security breaches are user issues, and there's little you can do for some cases.  Note the clause doesn't specify that the breach needs to be your fault! Personally, I'd run.

@DonQuiKong and limited liability companies (caveats apply).

How is "Security Breach" defined in the contract? I certainly hope it's defined as something you caused, not any security breach arising anywhere. Also the risk depends a lot on what you work on exactly, and what data you have access to (or give access to).

I think the relationships here are confusing.  How are you an employee with Subcontractor 2, which has a contract with Subcontractor 1, which has a contract with "Client" ?  You're either an employee of Subcontractor 1 or Subcontractor 2 or Client, not more than one at the same time ?  If you're not an employee then you're a contractor and that contract should be only with one of the other entities.  Even if you are employed by your own company, Subcontractor 1 would be hiring your company, Subcontractor 1, not yo, unless you're failed to set that language in the contract.

Why is this in an NDA? It seems like it should be in the service contract.

This makes very little sense. If you get paid through a W2, then you have employer and that employer is liable and would have to sign the NDA. Do you get paid through a W2 or a 1099?

I was the CEO of a software consulting company for 30 years and although I would need to see the rest of the contract to be sure (or at least the definition of "Security Breach"), as presented, there's no way that I would sign this for my company, nor would I let anyone in my company sign it personally.  This looks like a typical "tarbaby" clause (no matter what, you are always stuck) and I never agreed to any of them in three decades.  I was always able to get them removed or modified, or I walked away.  IANAL, but as a SW consultant, I would not recommend agreeing to this.

@Hilmar It is quite common in this industry for the hiring companies to require that all of the contractors and/or subcontractors to sign such things personally even if they are W2 employees of one of the contractor companies, and surprisingly most contractor companies go along with it.  I never did, and I would not allow any of our customers to require such things from our employees and was almost always able to get it removed (rare exceptions for certain Homeland Security rules).


I want to know if I am opening myself up to writing a blank check for
"SUBCONTRACTOR 1"?

If you cause a security breach, then yes.
It may be an insurable risk. I'm not familiar with that part of the insurance market.
You could try to negotiate a term that limits your liability, but you may or may not be able to get it. Often service providers have a blanket term in a contract limiting their liability to the amount that they were paid under the contract.
If the party to the contract is a limited liability company that you form, rather than you personally, and you don't personally guarantee this liability, then all you have to lose are the assets in the company. For a software engineer, those assets are often minimal.

The language doesn't specify that the breach needs to be the contractor's fault.

@ScottSeidman "Security Breach" is capitalised, so it's probably defined elsewhere in the contract. I hope that definition makes it clear that it needs to be the contractor's fault.

The wording of the paragraph does not limit it to "Security Breach"es caused by the SUBCONTRACTOR.  Of course the definition of Security Breach might so limit it, but I have seen many subcontracting that had no such limiting language.

@ScottSeidman Even if it didn't say that, I think you could get to a reading that this is the intent of the parties from any reasonable reading of the contract. It isn't described as an insurance contract for third-party wrongs that the subcontractor has no involvement in causing.

@ohwilleke How many millions of dollars are you willing to bet on that?  You win, you get 0$; you lose, you owe millions.
